# Interrupts: process context saved in PCB or kernel stack?

Tags: operating-system, stack, kernel, cpu, context-switch

I have searched and read several similar questions but still do not understand:

1. The PSW is a set of processor flags (carry, overflow, etc.).
   My book says that when an interrupt is generated the PSW and PC are saved on the control stack, the interrupt handler starts and finally the CPU state is restored: all the remaining registers, for example the user registers? Did the writer simply forget them or are they not saved at all?
2. Why are PSW and PC saved on the control stack and not on the PCB (where ALL processor registers would be saved)?

I can understand when a system call is executed (it is a synchronous interrupt): the processor switches to kernel mode and works on the kernel stack. But when does a clock interrupt happen and the OS decides to switch to another process? In that case it is mandatory to use the PCB and not the right stack?

My conclusion is that some interrupts can be managed with a separate stack in the kernel area but others require the PSW and PC to be saved in the PCB and not in the stack together with the other registers.
However, I would like an answer to my questions from you experts =)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'But when does a clock interrupt happen and the OS decides to switch to another process?' Clock?  You mean 'any hardware interrupt that causes a device driver to request a scheduling run on exit from interrupt state'.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts/IRQs have very little to do with task switches.

When CPU starts an interrupt handler it needs to change some things (e.g. PC) to start the interrupt handler, so it needs to store the old values so that they can be restored when the interrupt handler returns. The interrupt handler may store additional things (e.g. user registers), but may not (if it doesn't use them for anything itself); and in some cases (e.g. an IRQ that does only increments a counter) the interrupt handler could save almost nothing extra, use almost nothing, restore almost nothing, then return.

Depending on which OS and how it's supposed to work; if the interrupt handler feels like doing a task switch, then some of the interrupt handler's stuff (e.g. PC) would need to be saved somewhere. "Somewhere" could be directly in the PCB, but could be on the kernel's stack (with only stack pointer saved in PCB). Note that most operating systems use a high level language's calling conventions where only some things are "callee preserved" and other things can be trashed by the callee and therefore don't need to be saved anywhere during a task switch because the caller expected them to be trashed anyway.

Comment: ok, so when an interrupt occurs the processor saves the PSW and the registers in the kernel stack (is it the same as "control stack"?). When the handler finishes, a context switch may occurs and then the same information on the stack can also be saved on the PCB (it's the case of a clock interrupt)? It's right?

Comment: @BartDoe: No - when interrupt happens CPU + interrupt handler saves user state from registers; then if task switch happens the task switch code saves interrupt handler's state from registers (which are not user's state).

Comment: The kernel stack may well be a member of the PCB/TCB struct.  If a thread/process needs both a control/state struct and a kernel stack, why bother allocating them separately?   May as well kmalloc the lot in one go.